# angularjs parent ng-form valid even when directive ng-form is invalid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have writted a directive to generate input fields from scope fields, everything is working fine except that the parent ng-form stays invalid even though the ng-form within directive is invalid.

this is how i am checking the state of the form:

```
<ng-form name="parentForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <form-field ng-model="input.name" field="fields[0]" ng-change="changed(input.name)"></form-field>
    <form-field ng-model="input.age" field="fields[1]"></form-field>
    <pre> parent form: valid : {{parentForm.$valid}}</pre>
</ng-form>
```

and below is the link function

```
var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var fieldGetter = $parse(attrs.field);
    var field = fieldGetter(scope);
    var template = input(field, attrs); //genrate the template
    element.replaceWith($compile(template)(scope)); //replace element with templated code
};
```

i guess the problem is that i need to compile the parent element rather than the element itself to get validations working, but not sure on how to do it

```
      element.replaceWith($compile(template)(scope));
```

[PLUNKER LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/4JSRLr?p=preview)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the docs on **[FormController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)**, there is the `$addControl()` method that is used to:

*Register a control with the form.

Input elements using ngModelController do this automatically when they are linked.*

This gives us the hint that the "`ng-model`ed" elements will take care of everything in their link function as long as we give them the chance. Giving them the chance (in this context) means that they should be able to locate their parent `ngForm` element while linking.
You have been (quite small-heartedly) depriving them of this right, by first compiling **and** linking them and only then inserting them into the DOM <sub>(shame on you)</sub>.

Once you know the cause, the solution is easy:
You need to first insert them into the DOM and then link them.
E.g.:

```
// Instead of this:
element.replaceWith($compile(template)(scope));

// Which is equivalent to this:
var linkFunc = $compile(template);   // compiling
var newElem  = linkFunc(scope);      // linking
element.replaceWith(newElem);        // inserting

// You should do this:
var newElem = angular.element(template);   // creating
element.replaceWith(newElem);              // inserting
$compile(newElem)(scope);                  // compiling + linking
                                           // (could be done in 2 steps
                                           //  but there is no need)
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/quSX2lpN65v4XNTFdulF?p=preview)**.